# Problema con filtro personalizado usando Datatables

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Quiero cargar un datatable con los datos de una tabla mysql. Hasta ahí lo entiendo, pero quiero agregarle un filtro con un combo que en dependencia del valor seleccionado en este combo box refresco el datatable.

Cargo los datos en el script este:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'ajax': {
                'url':'data.php'
            },
            'columns': [
              { data: 'idp' },
              { data: 'def' },
              { data: 'est' },
              { data: 'obs' }
            ]
        });
```

Pero cómo paso el parámetro al `data.php` según la opción seleccionada en el combo box.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, debes poner el PHP y HTML del listado para ver cómo haces las consultas para poder responderte.

Comment: Por combobox te refieres a una lista tipo select?